# difference between "at" and "from"

Tags: meaning, phrase-meaning

I posted the following question to Lang-8.

I have a question.
Which one is correct?
1. The next meeting will be from 10:30.
2. The next meeting will be at 10:30.
What's the difference between these two sentences?

Then I got the following answer.

An event always occurs "at" a time.
ex.) I went to school at 7:00. I came home at 4:30.
If you are talking about the length of time, you can say "from"
ex) I was waiting at the airport from 3:00 to 4:00. Then we went sightseeing from 4:30 to 8:00.

Now, I have a new question.
If someone say "The next meeting will be from 10:30", does that sound strange? Or if someone say this sentence, what kind of meaning does it have?

Comment: It does sound strange. It has no meaning.

Answer (score 2):

They're right. If you want to specify that an event is to take place at a specific time, using the preposition *from* would be wrong. Your example containing *from* does sound strange and, what's more, unnatural. No one would ever say something like that. With time, the preposition that we tend to use most often would be *at*. For example:

> We will meet **at** 2 o'clock at the hot dog stand. So, I'll see you there.

You would use the construction *from ... to ...* (notice that it's two prepositions, not one) to specify the duration of an event (how long it lasts, in other words):

> The meeting lasted one hour, **from** 10:00 AM **to** 11:00 AM.

Answer (score 0):

Compare "from" with "starts"

The next meeting is going to start at 10:00

I think that would be equivalent to the "will be from"-expression in your mind.